How to change default values for compileSdk and targetSdk in Android Studio
Whenever I create a new project in Android Studio, it sets compileSdK and targetSdk to 34 and I have to manually change them to 35 (the latest version). Is there any way to have Android Studio create a new project with SDK version 35 automatically set for compileSdk and targetSDK?
To try to fix the issue, I unchecked Android 14.0 in the SDK Platforms tab of the SDK Manager, but that didn't seem to make any difference. New projects are still automatically created with compile and target SDKs of 34.
